# Making matrix within a function with an array as parameter in Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, matrix

I am trying to implement a function of two arguments in Python, which I would like to implicit-plot later.

This function **returns the determinant of a matrix that is defined inside it by using its two arguments.**

To make the plot, I define two numpy arrays, one for each argument, which will be the two axes in my plot later on.

My problem arrises when I pass these two arrays as parameters to my function: it tells me `"ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence".` I thought numpy was build to handle this sort of things, which is why I am confused and haven't been able to solve this by myself.

You can find the code I use below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np

def F(a,b):
    M = np.matrix([[a,2.0],[0.0,b]],dtype=np.float)
    return np.linalg.det(M)
    
X = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0, num=200)
Y = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0, num=200)
    
F(X,Y)
```

Comment: Which line causes the error? Did you google the error to see what solutions are already out there?

Comment: What do you expect `M = np.matrix([[a,2.0],[0.0,b]],dtype=np.float)` to make?

Comment: if you run your same code but use, `X = 2;Y = 3` you'll see that `F(X,Y)=6.0` ... Be careful with your types. Neither X nor Y are np.float types

Comment: That error happens when you try to put more than one thing into a single element slot of a numpy array. In your case, you put all the linspace elements into `a` and `b` at the same time, which obviously won't work. With a `@np.vectorize` decorator on `F` it should work, but probably not the fastest way. Also don't use `np.matrix`, use regular `np.array` instead.

Comment: Given those `X` and `Y` what do you expect `M` to be? This is a basic array construction issue.

Comment: `np.vectorize` does the job, thank you very much. I didn't know about the existence of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with how you try to create the matrix (here I'll use `np.array` instead of the older (and nearly deprecated) `np.matrix`:

With scalar values:

```
In [263]: a,b = 3,6                                                                                  
In [264]: np.array([[a,2.0],[0.0,b]], np.float)                                                      
Out[264]: 
array([[3., 2.],
       [0., 6.]])
```

But with list or arrays:

```
In [265]: a,b = [1,2],[3,4]                                                                          
In [266]: np.array([[a,2.0],[0.0,b]], np.float)                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-266-49cf30d8a5ca> in <module>
----> 1 np.array([[a,2.0],[0.0,b]], np.float)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

If I allow it to make an object, as opposed to float, array, I get:

```
In [267]: np.array([[a,2.0],[0.0,b]], object)                                                        
Out[267]: 
array([[list([1, 2]), 2.0],
       [0.0, list([3, 4])]], dtype=object)
```

See it's trying to put that list (or array) in the slot of the 2d array.  That's ok if we allow objects, as Python lists do, but not if we expect a float array.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish by putting arrays in the matrix?  Explain the logic.

---

### simple iteration:

```
In [273]: def F(a,b): 
     ...:     M = np.array([[a,2.0],[0.0,b]],dtype=np.float) 
     ...:     return np.linalg.det(M) 
     ...:      
     ...: X = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0, num=6) 
     ...: Y = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0, num=6)                                                           
In [274]:                                                                                            
In [274]: np.array([F(a,b) for a,b in zip(X,Y)])                                                     
Out[274]: array([ 0.,  1.,  4.,  9., 16., 25.])
```

### 3d array

Looks at the docs for `det`.

If you want the `det` for `M` (2,2) arrays, you need to create a (M,2,2) shaped array.

The example in `det` is:

```
>>> a = 
>>> a.shape
(3, 2, 2)
>>> np.linalg.det(a)
array([-2., -3., -8.])

In [269]: np.array([ [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[1, 3], [3, 1]] ])                         
Out[269]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [2, 1]],

       [[1, 3],
        [3, 1]]])
```

Creating such a `M` from your `X` and `Y`:

```
In [276]: M = np.zeros((X.shape[0],2,2))                                                             
In [277]: M[:,0,0]=X                                                                                 
In [278]: M[:,0,1]=2                                                                                 
In [279]: M[:,1,1]=Y                                                                                 
In [280]: M                                                                                          
Out[280]: 
array([[[0., 2.],
        [0., 0.]],

       [[1., 2.],
        [0., 1.]],

       [[2., 2.],
        [0., 2.]],

       [[3., 2.],
        [0., 3.]],

       [[4., 2.],
        [0., 4.]],

       [[5., 2.],
        [0., 5.]]])
In [281]: np.linalg.det(M)                                                                           
Out[281]: array([ 0.,  1.,  4.,  9., 16., 25.])
```

### 2d X vs Y

So far I show a 1d result, iterating on `X` and `Y` in parallel.  If you want a cartesian product, `X` and `Y` as two axes, we have to do something different.

```
In [283]: np.array([[F(a,b) for b in Y] for a in X])                                                 
Out[283]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  4.,  6.,  8., 10.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  6.,  9., 12., 15.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  8., 12., 16., 20.],
       [ 0.,  5., 10., 15., 20., 25.]])
```

### vectorize with broadcasting

When constructing a `X` versus `Y` result, `np.vectorize` is useful:

```
In [284]: f = np.vectorize(F, otypes=[float])                                                        
In [285]: f(X,Y)                                                                                     
Out[285]: array([ 0.,  1.,  4.,  9., 16., 25.])
In [286]: f(X[:,None],Y)                                                                             
Out[286]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  4.,  6.,  8., 10.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  6.,  9., 12., 15.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  8., 12., 16., 20.],
       [ 0.,  5., 10., 15., 20., 25.]])
```

The same function can be used both ways.

For a fully vectorized result, we need to make a 4d M:

```
In [287]: M = np.zeros((X.shape[0],Y.shape[0],2,2))                                                  
In [288]: M[:,:,0,0]=X[:,None]                                                                       
In [289]: M[:,:,0,1]=2                                                                               
In [290]: M[:,:,1,1]=Y[None,:]                                                                       
In [291]: np.linalg.det(M)                                                                           
Out[291]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  4.,  6.,  8., 10.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  6.,  9., 12., 15.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  8., 12., 16., 20.],
       [ 0.,  5., 10., 15., 20., 25.]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to plot this function implicitly: F(a,b) = 0. To make this plot I need an array for a and an array for b.

Comment: He wanted to substitute every element inside of `a` and `b` and get back an array with shape (200,). The solution (probably not the fastest) is just adding `np.vectorize` decorator. The question wasn't clear.

Comment: @PéterLeéh, why not just recommend iteration on the elements of `X` and `Y`?  That's more straightforward, and faster.

Comment: @hpaulj Well, that's fewer characters and easy to understand in comments. There are millions of questions about that with detailed answers.

Comment: @PéterLeéh, most of those SO involving `np.vectorize` deal with its pitfalls.  On the surface it's easy to use, but often it is misused.  I discourage its use unless you really need to broadcast several arrays against each other, and the function cannot be 'vectorized' in a proper manner.